# Spinner Item Selection - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, spinner

Hi Guys I am having trouble with a spinner Item selection. The concept is a calorie calculator and the current code that I have placed below is the button to calculate the action as well as the spinner listener. I have tested the users input which is working fine as well as testing what the spinner string is equaling, however it is not setting my if statement to true. Can anyone enlighten me on what is the issue?

```
enum Discount {
   STEAK(2.71f),
   CHICKEN(2.39f), 
   PORK(2.42f), 
   HAM(1.45f), 
   VEAL(1.72f), 
   WHITEFISH(1.72f), 
   SALMON(2.08f);

    private float amount;
    Discount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


}




dropDownList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemSelectedDiscount = dropDownList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



    Button calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            totalCaloriesInt = value;
            status.setText(itemSelectedDiscount);
            if (itemSelectedDiscount == "STEAK") {
            Discount steak = Discount.STEAK;
                calculatedCalories.setText("" + totalCaloriesInt * steak.amount);
            }

            else if (itemSelectedDiscount == "CHICKEN") {
                Discount chicken = Discount.CHICKEN;
                calculatedCalories.setText("" + totalCaloriesInt * chicken.amount);
            }


        }
    });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see all code but I suppose You Should use in Your if condition [string.equals(Object other)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) instead of "==" operator.

```
(itemSelectedDiscount.equals("STEAK"))
```